# issue with arguments to messages.properties, all numbers except zero work correctly

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

In my Grails 2.4.4 app I am using messages.properties for internationalization, with the following value:

```
my.app.thing.allowance(s)={0} Allowance(s)
```

and it is being using in a gsp like so:

```
<g:message code="my.app.thing.allowance(s)" args="${item.allowances.size()}"/>
```

the message is correctly displayed for any values greater than 0, for example if `item.allowances.size() == 4` then the message displayed is `4 Allowances(s)`

the issue is that if `item.allowances.size() == 0` then the message displayed is `{0} Allowance(s)`

I have tried to write the args in several different ways, for example:

```
<g:message code="my.app.thing.allowance(s)" args="${item.allowances.isEmpty() ? 0.intValue() : item.allowances.size()}"/>
```

I have debugged things and I am sure that `item.allowances.size() == 0` but for some reason it can not handle a value of 0 properly. What is the correct way to pass an argument with an int value of 0 to messages.properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `g.message` arguments are always passed as an `List`.

From: http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/ref/Tags/message.html

> args (optional) - A list of argument values to apply to the message when code is used.

Try this code instead:

```
<g:message code="my.app.thing.allowance(s)" args="[item.allowances.size()]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bharat's answer is correct, but I want to add why it happened so:
You have passed `args=0`
And here it is code from message tag lib:

```
List args = []
if (attrs.args) {
   args = attrs.encodeAs ? attrs.args as List : encodeArgsIfRequired(attrs.args)
   }
```

In groovy 0 is false, that's why you didn't have filled in message in case of ZERO